# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') From three.module.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I building a simple web for my final project.
I got a problem with the UnrealBloomPass. if I didn't add the pass to the compositor it works just fine. I check everything and follow the examples from repo it should be worked but I don't know what went wrong.

Here's some the rough code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {EffectComposer} from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js';
import {RenderPass} from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js';
import {UnrealBloomPass} from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js';

function init() {
  var loader = new OBJLoader();
  loader.load("/model/graphs.obj",

    function (grapics) {
      window.stage = new Stage(grapics);
    });

}

window.addEventListener("load", init);

function Stage(obj) {
  window.objA = obj.children[0];
  window.objB = obj.children[1];

  this.init();
  this.createMesh();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
};

Stage.prototype.init = function () { 
  this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
  this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.querySelector("#bg")
  });
  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  this.ambient = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x53EEEE, 0x111142, 0.5);
  this.scene.add(this.ambient);
  this.scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x0b1b2d, 1, 20);
  this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);

  this.ambient.intensity = 0.1;
  this.renderScene = new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera);
  this.bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), 0.3, 1.4, 0.002);

  this.composer = new EffectComposer(this.renderer);
  this.composer.addPass(this.renderScene);
  this.composer.addPass(this.bloomPass);

Stage.prototype.addParticle= function () {...}
Stage.prototype.createMesh= function () {...}
Stage.prototype.raycastUpdate= function () {...}
Stage.prototype.handleEvents= function () {...}
Stage.prototype.updateWin= function () {...}

Stage.prototype.render = function () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    this.updateCamera();
    this.raycastUpdate();
    this.handleEvents();
    this.updateWin();

    ///Particles Update
    for (var i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
      this.particles[i].update(this);
    }
    this.composer.render();
}

function Particle(scene) {...}
Particle.prototype.update = function (stage) {...}
```

The error occur at |  Stage.prototype.render |>>>| this.composer.render(); | with log message:

```
three.module.js:28286 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at setProgram (three.module.js:28286:32)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (three.module.js:27177:19)
    at renderObject (three.module.js:27807:10)
    at renderObjects (three.module.js:27776:5)
    at renderScene (three.module.js:27698:35)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.module.js:27518:4)
    at FullScreenQuad.render (Pass.js:62:12)
    at UnrealBloomPass.render (UnrealBloomPass.js:228:15)
    at EffectComposer.render (EffectComposer.js:141:9)
    at Stage.render (main.js?t=1664188647747:461:19)
```

Comment: so I have no ThreeJs knowledge, but it would seem that you call .render before assigning a value to `particles` in Stage. You could initialize particles as en empty array in your init